# UIButton text not updating when pop back to View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

1st VC --> 2nd VC --> 3rd VC
then, pops back from
1st VC <-- 3rd VC.

The text of the cell selected on 3rd VC is stored in NSUserDefaults, and I use that text to fill a UIButton's text on the 1st VC.

The problem is that the text in the UIButton doesn't refresh/change it pops back to 1st VC from 3rd VC.  The text is only refreshed when I stop the app and then re-run (in XCode Simulator).

So its saving the text in the NSUserDefaults correctly, but when it pops back to 1st VC, somehow the UIButton isn't refreshing.

Any help for how to get that UIButton to refresh when I pop back to the 1st VC?

-EDIT-
Code snippets for 1st VC:

```
// Grab text from defaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *teamNameOne = [defaults objectForKey:@"teamName1"];
// Set button Title
[buttonOne setTitle:teamNameOne forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: @JoshCaswell I updated the code to reflect the code snippet you requested.  Hope that helps, let me know if you need any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that after you save the value to `NSUserDefaults` in your 3rd VC, that you synchronize:

```
[defaults synchronize];
```

That updates the store with the recently set values.

Three other things to check:

1. Make sure that the button you are setting the title for is in fact in the Normal control state once the First VC gets loaded up.
2. Make sure the call to populate that button title in the First VC is done in viewWillAppear and not in viewDidLoad.  When working with a navigation controller, the viewDidLoad isn't called when popping back to an already loaded view.  Also make sure to call the super:

   ```
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

       NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       NSString *buttonTitle = [defaults valueForKey:@"ButtonTitle"];

       [self.myButton setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   ```
3. Make sure you are populating the NSUserDefaults store prior to popping back to the First VC.

Here is a project I just built that does what you are needing (very simple project):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3660978/SO_ViewControllerTransition.zip

Comment: Yup, I've got the synchronize code on the 3rd VC, so I know that part is working.  Thanks for the heads up just in case though.  Any other thoughts on what it might be?

Comment: I just swapped the code into viewWillAppear and it worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!  And thanks for the link to your project, that helped clarify too.  You rock.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good use for NSUserDefaults -- it's not meant to be a temporary holding place for values you're passing around in your app.

You should do this with an unwind segue. You can pass data back to VC1 in the prepareForSegue method, just like you would for a normal forward segue. You will also have a method in VC1 (the one you hook up the unwind segue to) that can be used to update your UI in that controller.

Comment: Totally agree with rdelmar.  My answer was to try and figure out why what you are doing isn't working (because it should work), but the right way to do it is with an unwind segue.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for the response.  I've never read much on the unwind segue, but I will now to see if it fits better into what I'm doing!